# how to read duplicate nodes from XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

As you can see in the below xml there are two duplicate fields or nodes called condition (one in `<current_conditions>` and the other in `<forecast_conditions>`. so whenever i use the `startelement` method to read the condition I always get the last last one but i want to read from the first node only).

```
<current_conditions>
<condition data="Mostly Cloudy"/>
<temp_f data="86"/>
<temp_c data="30"/>
<humidity data="Humidity: 25%"/>
<icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_cloudy.gif"/>
<wind_condition data="Wind: SE at 7 mph"/>
</current_conditions>

<forecast_conditions>
<day_of_week data="Sun"/>
<low data="73"/>
<high data="97"/>
<icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
<condition data="Mostly Sunny"/>
```

I can I do that. I am using SAX parser to parse the document and here is the code for the handler I am using

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
   if (localName.equals("condition")) {
     String data=attributes.getValue("data");
}}
```

Comment: oops it didn't update properly let me repaste it

Comment: Perhaps this almost exact same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796041/selecting-specific-xml-tags-with-sax-parser) (which even uses the same weather-related XML) might help.

Comment: yup thank you Ken I do agree that the link to that question is really helpful but at the same time I was thinking if there was a more graceful solution to this problem rather than rewriting the reading  logic with lots of if else statements. As this is only a simple example I gave but think about when the number of duplicate fields is large or when the outer nodes are dynamic and the internal nodes are duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't find one so had to do it the hard way ....wrote the logic myself with modifications to the link provided by Ken...